# running appengine with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, installation

I am trying to run a sample program using app engine with eclipse. i install google plug in according to instructions in this site : 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/installing

following the tutorial. but for some reason my app w'ont run. I get the following mistakes :

```
     14/12/2012 14:13:41 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
     INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
     14/12/2012 14:13:41 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
     INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\rona\workspace\Guestbook\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
     14/12/2012 14:13:41 com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
     SEVERE: Received exception processing C:\Users\rona\workspace\Guestbook\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
     com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element.
     See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests for more information.
     You probably want to enable concurrent requests.
     at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.readAppEngineWebXml(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:79)
     at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:130)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.loadAppEngineWebXml(AbstractContainerService.java:334)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.initContext(JettyContainerService.java:160)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:227)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
     com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid appengine-web.xml(C:\Users\rona\workspace\Guestbook\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml) - appengine-web.xml does not contain a <threadsafe> element.
     See http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Using_Concurrent_Requests for more information.
     You probably want to enable concurrent requests.
     at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:132)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.loadAppEngineWebXml(AbstractContainerService.java:334)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.initContext(JettyContainerService.java:160)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:227)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:157)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:333)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:269)
     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:245)
```

the code for the app is from google developer copied exactly the same. I know the program run on another computer. something in my installation just dose't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include the following chunk in your appengine-web.xml:

```
<threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
```

It is mandatory to explicitly set expectations whether your application is designed in a thread-safe way.